# fasti image classification used only validation dataset not test dataset

Tags: fast-ai

I used fastai to build a image classification model. I provided training and validation dataset like this:

```
data = (ImageList.from_folder(PATH)
        .split_by_folder(train='train', valid='valid')
        .label_from_folder()
        .transform(get_transforms(do_flip=True, flip_vert= True,max_zoom=1.1, max_rotate=10, max_lighting=0.5),size=224)
        .databunch()
        .normalize() )
```

and then I ran the 3-4 epochs which gave me loss and accuracy at each epoch

and in the end I generated confusion matrix.

```
interp = ClassificationInterpretation.from_learner(learn)
interp.plot_confusion_matrix()
```

My question is,

1. shouldnt I be using a separate test dataset to acutally calculating the confusion matrix and actual accuracy. Or just using of validation datatest is sort of enough. I am hoping the just use of validation dataset is good enough in terms of finding the model accuracy.
2. I understand the validation data set is used to fine tune the hyperparameter for next epoch, So, in the end of the last epoch, can the validation data set be considered as test dataset?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a question about fast-ai, but more about data science in general. I'm definitely not an expert but I'll try to explain it the way it's been explained to me.

```
for each set of hyper parameters:
   for each epoch:
      train the model with training data
      test on the validation data (not used in training)
      some stopping criteria?
   Look at trained model, e.g. confusion matrix, other stats
   Stop hyper parameter search if good enough (for production or a paper, etc)
```

Test, once, on the test set (not used in training or validation), and use the results of that test in a paper, or a report to management or a blog post, etc. Whether you actually have a separate test set or not would depend on how you're going to use the trained model.

Since I mostly do this as a hobby, I don't bother with a test set. If you are doing something like a competition, then there is probably a set of data you never get to see, which would be used like a test set once you submit your results.